# How to generate 64 bit apk for ionic 1 application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, 64-bit, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-proguard

I have used below plugins in my project and I have tried all the methods to generate the 64 bit APK for store release. Please let me know if anyone know how to generate the 64 bit apk for the ionic 1 project

```
com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot 0.1.5 "Screenshot"
com.godbtech.sqliteplugin 1.0.0 "GoDBSqliteEE"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-appavailability 0.4.2 "AppAvailability"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-crop 0.3.1 "CropPlugin"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.3.0 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-proguard 1.0.0 "Cordova plugin ProGuard"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.3 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-root-detection 0.1.1 "Root Detection"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.3.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.2.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.7.2 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error while uploading in the play store?
If you have no native (NDK) code, that is you only write Java/Dex code, then you don't need to do anything

Comment: Play store gives an error as it required 64 bit apk when I analyzed generated apk it has a lib folder with .so file which signifies this is a 32 bit apk.

Comment: is it any plugin that is generating that .so file. Can you tell more about the .so file?